# Windows server 2012 r2 core interface disable

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

I successfully installed windows server 2012 R2 .After setting admin password,and login,I am getting command window instead of GUI.
Can anyone please help me come out of this issue.I tried several methods but still in midst of problem.

Waiting for reply..

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you did infact install Windows core version. Make a new installation and select Windows server (with GUI) from the menu. If youre not prompted this during installation, then it is most likely not the correct install media.